# Triggering TexBlock Style upon Updating of another element

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding

I am new to WPF development and trying to make a user interface for a complex parametric model.  In my ViewModel there are two instances of a Configuration class that I wrote: WorkingConfig is immediately updated every time the user interacts with the interace, and SavedConfig is updated only when the user pressed a "Calculate" button.

Most of my user interface consists of stacked pairs of TextBlocks and various simple input elements, such as TextBoxes, ComboBoxes and CheckBoxes.  Whenever the user changes a value in one of the input elements, and therefore changes the WorkingConfig, I want the corresponding TextBlock to change its style if the new value is not equal to the value stored in the SavedConfig.  Thereby the user can visually keep track of which values they've changed without recalculating.

To do this per TextBlock seems to involve an enormous amount of copy-pasted code just to set up different bindings for each TextBlock, so I'm trying to find a generic solution using a style.  With some digging and some ChatGPT I've set up an attached property that corresponds to the name of the attribute to be checked, and a MultiValueConverter to check the value of the named attribute for both the WorkingConfig and the SavedConfig:

```
public static class AttachedProperty
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AttributeNameProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AttributeName",typeof(string), typeof(AttachedProperty));

    public static string GetAttributeName(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(AttributeNameProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAttributeName(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AttributeNameProperty, value);
    }
}

public class AttributeComparisonConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Length == 3 && values[0] is IConfiguration config1 && values[1] is IConfiguration config2 )
        {
            string AttributeName = values[2]?.ToString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AttributeName)) { return true; }
            return string.Equals(GetAttributeValue(config1, AttributeName), GetAttributeValue(config2, AttributeName));
        }
        return false;
    }

    private string GetAttributeValue(IConfiguration config, string AttributeName)
    {
        return config?.GetType().GetProperty(AttributeName).GetValue(config)?.ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

In the style, I bind the config elements and the attached property that should be checked for all TextBlocks.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:core="clr-namespace:my_core_namespace">
    <core:AttributeComparisonConverter x:Key="AttributeComparisonConverter"/>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}"
           TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkSlateGray"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Light"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15, 10, 0, 5"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="False">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource AttributeComparisonConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="WorkingConfig"/>
                        <Binding Path="SavedConfig"/>
                        <Binding Path="(core:AttachedProperty.AttributeName)" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then in a given UserControl, I simply assign the name of the attribute that should be checked for each TextBlock:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="240"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="example 1" core:AttachedProperty.AttributeName="property1"/>
        <TextBlock Text="example 2" core:AttachedProperty.AttributeName="attribute2"/>
        <TextBlock Text="example 3" core:AttachedProperty.AttributeName="attribute3"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox_1" Text="{Binding WorkingConfig.attribute1}"/>
        <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox_1" Text="{Binding WorkingConfig.attribute2}"/>
        <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox_1" Text="{Binding WorkingConfig.attribute3}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This seems to sort of work, except that the comparison is only triggered when the UserControl is created, not every time a value is updated.  I understand that there is nothing in my DataTrigger that is actually triggered every time the monitored attribute is updated.  But I'm not sure how to change this in a generic fashion.

Sorry for the long post and I hope my issue is understandable.  Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Consider assigning a new value to the WorkingConfig property, instead of just changing a property of the IConfiguration that it references. You would thus trigger the MultiBinding. You may also improve the converter by replacing string comparison with object comparison by omitting the `.ToString()` call.

Comment: @MatthewJohnson: Add a binding to a property that actually gets set to a new value to the `MultiBinding`. This is required for the converter to be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your explanations correctly. You have two source properties "WorkingConfig" and "SavedConfig" with the same nested properties. Nestedproperties are notified of their change using INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged. If they don't, then your task can only be implemented if you replace the instance in the "SavedConfig" property after saving the data and implement INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged for the "SavedConfig" property.
For the task itself, you want to get a certain Boolean value indicating the difference between the “WorkingConfig” and “SavedConfig” properties of the same name. You set the property name in the "AttachedProperty.AttributeName" property.

In my opinion, you will need two more properties for implementation, since it will not be possible to create the binding you require in XAML.
One property will receive the values "WorkingConfig" and "SavedConfig". This property will create a binding in code using a value comparison converter. And then it will add this binding to the second property, the value of which will determine your style.

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace CommonCore.Converters
{

    [ValueConversion(typeof(object), typeof(Array))]
    public class ToArrayConverter : IValueConverter, IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return new object[] { value };
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            object[] copy = new object[values.Length];
            values.CopyTo(copy, 0);
            return copy;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        // Если нет членов экземпляра, то нет и смысла в конструкторе экземпляра.
        private ToArrayConverter() { }

        public static ToArrayConverter Instance { get; } = new();
    }

    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(NullToBoolConverter))]
    public class ToArrayExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return ToArrayConverter.Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Markup;

namespace Converters
{
    public class AllEqualsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        private AllEqualsConverter() { }

        public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values?.Length > 1)
            {
                object first = values[0];
                return values.Skip(1).All(item => Equals(item, first));
            }
            return true;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public static AllEqualsConverter Instance { get; } = new AllEqualsConverter();
    }

    [MarkupExtensionReturnType(typeof(AllEqualsConverter))]
    public class AllEqualsExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
            => AllEqualsConverter.Instance;
    }
}
```

```cs
using Converters;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace Core2023.SO.MatthewJohnson.questions77620925
{
    public static class AttachedProperties
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AttributeNameProperty
            = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "AttributeName",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(AttachedProperties),
                new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
                {
                    CoerceValueCallback = (_, e) => e is null ? string.Empty : e,
                    PropertyChangedCallback = (d, e) => AllChanged(d, GetArrayOfValues(d), (string)e.NewValue)
                });

        public static string GetAttributeName(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(AttributeNameProperty);
        }

        public static void SetAttributeName(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(AttributeNameProperty, value);
        }
        public static IList<object> GetArrayOfValues(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (IList<object>)obj.GetValue(ArrayOfValuesProperty);
        }

        public static void SetArrayOfValues(DependencyObject obj, IList<object> value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(ArrayOfValuesProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ArrayOfValues.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ArrayOfValuesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "ArrayOfValues",
                typeof(IList<object>),
                typeof(AttachedProperties),
                new PropertyMetadata(Array.Empty<object>())
                {
                    CoerceValueCallback = (_, e) => e is null ? Array.Empty<object>() : e,
                    PropertyChangedCallback = (d, e) => AllChanged(d, (IList<object>)e.NewValue, GetAttributeName(d))
                });

        private static readonly ConditionalWeakTable<DependencyObject, DpProxy> table = new();
        private class DpProxy : DependencyObject
        {
            public readonly DependencyObject Parent;

            public DpProxy(DependencyObject parent)
            {
                Parent = parent;
            }
            public bool? IsEqualsProxy
            {
                get { return (bool?)GetValue(IsEqualsProxyProperty); }
                set { SetValue(IsEqualsProxyProperty, value); }
            }

            // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsEquals.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
            public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEqualsProxyProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register(
                    "IsEqualsProxy",
                    typeof(bool?),
                    typeof(DpProxy),
                    new PropertyMetadata((bool?)null)
                    {
                        PropertyChangedCallback = IsEqualsChanged
                    });

        }

        private static void IsEqualsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DpProxy proxy = (DpProxy)d;
            SetIsEquals(proxy.Parent, (bool?)e.NewValue);
        }

        private static void AllChanged(DependencyObject d, IList<object> sources, string propertyPath)
        {
            if (sources.Count < 2)
            {
                if (table.TryGetValue(d, out DpProxy? proxy))
                {
                    proxy.ClearValue(DpProxy.IsEqualsProxyProperty);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!table.TryGetValue(d, out DpProxy? proxy))
                {
                    proxy = new(d);
                    table.Add(d, proxy);
                }
                object working = sources[0];
                object saved = sources[1];

                MultiBinding bindingEquals = new()
                {
                    Converter = AllEqualsConverter.Instance
                };
                bindingEquals.Bindings.Add(new Binding(propertyPath) { Source = working });
                bindingEquals.Bindings.Add(new Binding(propertyPath) { Source = saved });

                BindingOperations.SetBinding(proxy, DpProxy.IsEqualsProxyProperty, bindingEquals);
            }
        }

        public static bool? GetIsEquals(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (bool?)obj.GetValue(IsEqualsProperty);
        }

        private static void SetIsEquals(DependencyObject obj, bool? value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(IsEqualsPropertyKey, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for IsEquals.  
        public static readonly DependencyPropertyKey IsEqualsPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly(
                "IsEquals",
                typeof(bool?),
                typeof(AttachedProperties),
                new PropertyMetadata((bool?)null));
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEqualsProperty = IsEqualsPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    }
}
```

```xml
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="15, 10, 0, 5"/>
        <Setter Property="core:AttachedProperties.ArrayOfValues">
            <Setter.Value>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{cnvs:ToArray}">
                    <Binding Path="WorkingConfig"/>
                    <Binding Path="SavedConfig"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="core:AttachedProperties.IsEquals"
                     Value="False">
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**P.S.** I warn you right away. I wrote the code (based on my personal library) largely here in the message editor.
Therefore, there may be minor errors.